# I'm trying to put a fixed division at the top of the page but when I scroll with FF, lines are lost

Tags: css-position

THERE IS AN EDIT AT THE BOTTOM - look for **"===== EDIT ===="**

I am putting a fixed division at the top of the page. No problem with positioning it, but a problem comes up when I test the page by scrolling up and down.

Everything is fine with Chrome and IE but FF has a problem. The problem is that lines are "lost" under the fixed division. That is, the page is scrolled too far.

[Here is the test page](http://thetesting.site/scrolltest.shtml) The entire source for the page is at the bottom of this question.

The division on the test page has width: 80%; margin-left: 50px; and opacity: 0.5 This allow you to see the lines underneath the division.

Go to the test page and highlight the last line at the bottom of the viewport. Highlighting the last line makes it easy to spot when you PgDn.

Now PgDn (or click the scroll bar - the bar, not the slider)

You can repeat the highlighting and PgDn and it should behave the same way.

With Chrome and IE, the highlighted line will still be visible, more importantly the lines following it will be visible.

With FF, the highlighted line, and one or two of the lines after it, winds up underneath the fixed division. The lines after the highlighted line are lost -  not visible.

I've see this done successfully on other sites but I can't figure out what they are doing to make it work.

[This page works correctly with FF, Chrome, and IE.](http://www.quackit.com/) There are others but I can't seem to find them right now.

[Here is a page with the same problem as my test page](http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-a-floating-navigation-menu/demo/complete.html) It is different in that it "floats" the division until it is scrolled to the top and then it "fixes" it at the top. I've done this same float/fix thing and it also has the problem with FF. The test page I pointed you at, above, simply fixes the division to start with.

The funny thing about that page which has the same problem as mine is that it is a demo [of how to put a fixed division at the top of the page](http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-a-floating-navigation-menu/) and it doesn't work for FF

Another page with the problem of losing lines under the fixed division is yahoo.com. Lines are lost under the fixed division pretty much as is happening on my test page, but yahoo "loses" more lines than my test page.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix a division at the top and not lose lines underneath the division, lines which should be visible after the scroll? My test works for Chrome and IE but not for FF.

AND - wasn't there a code snippet link on the question page which you could use to provide demonstration code? I don't see it on this page where I'm typing the question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>Scroll Test</title>
    </head>

    <body style="margin-top: 0px;">
        <div style="clear: both; opacity: 0.5; margin-left: 50px; width: 80%; background-color: red; top: 0px; position: fixed; height: 50px;"></div>
        <div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                for (i = 0; i <201; i++) {
                    document.writeln("*** " + i + "*************************************************************************************<br>");
                }
            </script>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

By the way - the division (with the pink background) at the right hand side of this page has a problem when it get's fixed to the top of the viewport - the top is cut off. The only way to see the top is to scroll back up to the top of the page. This happens in FF, IE, and Chrome.

Where should I report this problem - about the "ask question page" - and provide the details?

**===== EDIT ====**

Thanks to user3137702, who told me to change the division to 100%. When I did that, the scrolling worked but initially when the page is loaded, lines #1 and #2 were under the fixed division.

I had the body set to margin: 0px; I changed that to margin-top: 50px; to make the first lines visible. I wasn't worried about the other margins - left, right, bottom, that's why I just changed the margin: 0px; to margin-top: 50px; - easiest to type.

- but that through me back into the original error. After playing with it for a while, I found that unless margin-left: 0px; is set on the body tag, the scrolling won't work.

So, the complete solution is to have the fixed division set to width: 100%; and the body set to margin-left: 0px; and margin-top: nnpx, where nn is the height of the fixed division.

I'll add some JavaScript to set the body top margin based on the height of the fixed division so I don't have to mess around with it if the height of the fixed division changes.

I originally had width: 80px; on the division because I want the fixed division to show as less that the body width and centered.

I took the code that solves the problem and added a second division under the fixed division. The fixed division has background-color: transparent; and width: 100%. The nested div is where the content is and is set to width: 80% margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto to center it.

Now the it displays as I want it to and it scrolls properly.

Here's the new definition of the body down to the close of the fixed division's tag:

```
<body style="margin: 0px; margin-top: 50px;">
 <div style="width: 100%; background-color: transparent;  top: 0px; position: fixed;">
    <div style="width: 80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: red; height: 50px;">
        Contents of the child division within the fixed division
    </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

[Here is a page incorporates all of the changes](http://thetesting.site/scrolltestresolved.shtml)

Again, thank you user3137702, I'll select your answer.

**Hold everything**

I just played with the fixed page and have found that IE, FF, and Chrome all start to have problems with the scrolling as the viewport becomes shorter - as would happen if you resize the browser window or pull up something like FireBug.

I'm not going to spend any time figuring out the size that causes the browsers to start misbehaving, it would be a waste of time. Suffice to say IE and Chrome start having problems at larger heights than does FF. But the sizes are something that it is unlikely anyone will ever encounter. The viewport has to get pretty short to start the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain exactly why it's happening, but it's the width that's messing up firefox; If you set the width of your fixed div to 100%, it works as you would expect.

```
<div style="background-color: red; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: fixed; height: 50px; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Look at the edit of the original question where I document the changes needed to get it working properly. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks.  I did forget to mention in my test that I also added a top margin -- but in your example the box was semi-transparent and the first few lines started under the div in all three browsers, so I thought maybe you wanted it that way.

Comment: No, in "production" I want everything to be visible below the fixed division. I made it semi-transparent so the position of all lines could be seen during testing. In production the division will be opaque.